# How do I append to PATH environment variable when running a Docker container?

Tags: docker

I want to mount a volume and add it to the container's PATH environment variable. I've tried the following and none is working.

```
docker run -it -v $(PWD):/app -e PATH=$PATH:/app/bin debian:jessie bash
docker run -it -v $(PWD):/app -e PATH='$PATH:/app/bin' debian:jessie bash
docker run -it -v $(PWD):/app -e PATH='$$PATH:/app/bin' debian:jessie bash
docker run -it -v $(PWD):/app -e PATH='\$PATH:/app/bin' debian:jessie bash
```

How do I append the mounted volume to PATH?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you you use -e option, the $PATH value is the PATH of the host instead of the container.

You can do it like this:

```
docker run -it -v $(PWD):/app debian:jessie bash -c 'export PATH=$PATH:/app/bin; bash'
```

Comment: This is almost working. Except I have to replace the double quotes with single quotes otherwise it will use the host's PATH instead of the container's PATH.

Comment: Docker run -c is now
 --cpu-shares int                 CPU shares (relative weight)

Answer (score 8):

Within the docker command line, you can't get "what will be the value of $PATH at runtime". Thus, you cannot append a PATH to the PATH variable, with docker's `-e` flag. To achieve what you want to do, you will need to do that in a script that will get executed as the cmd / entrypoint of your container.

Comment: While it is technically correct that you can't append with the `-e` flag, @KiwenLau provided a working solution above.

Answer (score 6):

You can define a fixed Path for your imported Apps and add the new Path to the Apps into the Environment-Variable "**Path**"

Let's take your Path "**/app**". In your Dockerfile add the following Line:

```
ENV PATH=${PATH}:/app/bin
```

Build your modified Docker

Now you can access all Apps located under **< external Directory >/bin** that you mount to "**/app**" via

```
-v <external Directory>:/app
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a shell script (let's call it *run.sh*):

```bash
#!/bin/sh -l

PATH=$PATH:/app/bin
"$@"
```

and call it from docker:

```
docker run -it -v $(PWD):/app debian:jessie /app/run.sh bash
```

Comment: what about `ENTRYPOINT`, isn't that the proper manner to do it?